# Sticky Nav flickering like flashing lights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote the code to make the nav to be a sticky nav, but the code that I wrote to make it a sticky nav is causing the sticky nav to blink, why? Where is the fault?

Here is my code :

```
;(function($) {

    $.fn.tosticky = function(o) {

        o = $.extend({

            tofixedClass: 'classtofixed',
            fixedClass: 'fixedclass',
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0

        }, o);

        return this.each(function() {

            var $window = $(window),
                $this = $(this);    

            $window.on("scroll", function() {
                var fence = $(o.tofixedClass).offset().top;
                var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
                if(scrollTop > fence) {
                    $(o.tofixedClass).addClass(o.fixedClass).css({"margin-top":o.top,"margin-bottom":o.bottom});
                } else {
                    $(o.tofixedClass).removeClass(o.fixedClass);
                }  
            });

        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function () { 
    $(".pagar").tosticky({ // use this to run code in above
        tofixedClass: '.pagar',
        fixedClass: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0 
    });
});
```

And here is my code in jsfiddle : [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bagusa4/1wxggpv5/4/)

Comment: try relacing your else with : `} else if (scrollTop < fence) {
                    $(o.tofixedClass).removeClass(o.fixedClass);
                }  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because when your element reaches the top of the window, its distance from the top becomes equal to `$(this).scrollTop();`, so you'll have to include cases where these are equal, otherwise the other part of the `if` statement will be true, thus the `fixedClass` will be removed, then re-added again when you do some scrolling, then the whole thing starts again, hence the flickering.

To correct this, just replace the *greater than* sign (`>`) with *greater than or equal* sign (`>=`) in your `if` statement:

```
if(scrollTop >= fence) {
    $(o.tofixedClass).addClass(o.fixedClass).css({"margin-top":o.top,"margin-bottom":o.bottom});
} else {
    $(o.tofixedClass).removeClass(o.fixedClass);
}
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1wxggpv5/6/

**EDIT**: following your comment, although this wasn't part of your original question, I understand you want the box to remain where it is, and the whole thing to go back to its original position when you scroll back up.

To do that, you'll have to move `#box` inside `.pagar` and move your `fence` variable out of the `on.scroll` function as follows:

jQuery (the relevant bits):

```
return this.each(function() {

    var $window = $(window),
        $this = $(this),   
        fence = $(o.tofixedClass).offset().top;

    $window.on("scroll", function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop >= fence) {
            $(o.tofixedClass).addClass(o.fixedClass).css({"margin-top":o.top,"margin-bottom":o.bottom});
        } else {
            $(o.tofixedClass).removeClass(o.fixedClass);
        }  
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "pagar">
    If you scroll past me, then you'll *NOT* see such as flashing lights flickering, and we now know why :)
    <div id = "box">
        Oh hello! :D
    </div>
</div>
<div class="scroll"></div>
```

I updated your original fiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/1wxggpv5/19/

Comment: yeah, but the statement you made ​​sticky nav cannot go back like nav (no fixed nav) originally, why ?? :)

Comment: Please See this http://jsfiddle.net/bagusa4/1wxggpv5/7/ and http://jsfiddle.net/bagusa4/1wxggpv5/8/ :)

Comment: yes, I can see them both, i see the difference... apparently my solution got rid of the flickering, wasn't that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: i just edited my answer, hope i understood well what you wanted to have, though i don't think it's part of the original question...

Comment: Your good man :D,,, Okay thanks for your help :)
Sorry troublesome :)

Answer (score 0):

This get flickers because you every time set the top of the fixed nav, whicle scrolling.To overcome this I use setTimeout and clearTime out.

```
            $.fn.tosticky = function(o) {

                    o = $.extend({

                        tofixedClass: 'classtofixed',
                        fixedClass: 'fixedclass',
                        top: 0,
                        bottom: 0

                    }, o);

                    return this.each(function() {
                        var timeoutId = null;
                        var $window = $(window),
                            $this = $(this);    

                        $window.on("scroll", function() {

                            if(timeoutId){
                                clearTimeout(timeoutId);                    
                            }
                           var fence = $(o.tofixedClass).offset().top;
                            var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
                            if(scrollTop > fence) {
                                timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){$(o.tofixedClass).addClass(o.fixedClass).css({"margin-top":o.top,"margin-bottom":o.bottom});}, 200);    
                            } else {
                                $(o.tofixedClass).removeClass(o.fixedClass);
                            } 
                        });



                    });
                };
```

Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisek101088/376scj34/embedded/result/);

Here in the scroll function I used the setTimeout and clearTimeout function.

Comment: this solution only has an effect once you reached the bottom of the scrollable region, in-between the menu is totally missing...

Answer (score 0):

it might be because one of / maybe all your '`.offset().top;`' is inside the scroll function which means everytime you scroll it resets the "top" heres my code that worked for me

```
var nav = $('.nav-wrapper');

    var NavTp = $('.nav-wrapper').offset().top;


   $(document).scroll(function () 
{
       var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll <= NavTp) {  
            nav.css({ "position": "static"});
            nav.removeClass('addfix');
        }
        else {
            nav.addClass('addfix');
        }

    });

.addfix {
  position: fixed!important;
  z-index: 999;
  top:0;
}

.nav-wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    background: #2c2c2c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can Stop flickering screen by adding below css

```css
th,td{border:1px solid #ccc}

th {padding: 1em 0.5em;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 6;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div style="max-height:300px; overflow:auto"><table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
        <tr>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
            <th>asdf</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="bodyTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="z-index:9;">
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```